# When I use Google Login in React, the response returns me CORS. How can i fix it?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, cors

When I use Google Register, the response returns me CORS. I am not sure maybe it is a Backend problem and don't know how can I fix it. My error:

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'link' (redirected from 'https://nehra.az/api/oauth/google') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

React Login code

```
  const token = Cookies.getItem("XSRF-TOKEN");
  const headers = {
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token,
  };

const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    let defualtValue = "994";
    setloader(true);
    const dt = new FormData();
    dt.append("name", response.profileObj.name);
    dt.append("email", response.profileObj.email);
    dt.append("phone", defualtValue);
    dt.append("password", response.accessToken);
    dt.append("auth_type", 3);
    axios
      .get("https://nehra.az/api/oauth/google", dt, headers)
      .then((res) => {
        setloader(false);
        if (res.status === 200) {
          localStorage.setItem("LoginUserData", JSON.stringify(res.data));
          CloseLoginF();
          closeRegisterF();
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => (setloader(false), setError(true)));
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

The backend server should add Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header for your localhost:3000 origin (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin), but it seems that the backend code could not be edited, given that circumstances.
If you use webpack dev server, you could use webpack proxy feature to avoid CORS error temporarily on localhost:3000.
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy